# ethereum mining - amount actually mined is

Tags: ethereum, mining

Im trying my luck on ethereum mining with this, can someone tell me how much ethereum I have mined and how to cash it :)

https://github.com/angelomilan/ethereum-guides/blob/master/GPU-cloud_mining.md

```
> eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase).toNumber();
5000000000000000000
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase), "ether")
5
```

What is 5000000000000000000 and what is 5 ?

Comment: Belongs on https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5000000000000000000 is your balance in wei, which represents 5 ethers.

[image]

Comment: do you know how to sell it ?

Comment: You’ll have to go on an exchange and follow their instructions in order to do that.